# How to transform a 3D bounding box from pointclouds to matched RGB frames in ROS?

Tags: rgb, ros, point-clouds, bounding-box, slam

i am doing SLAM with depth camera realsense D455 on ROS (https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/wiki/SLAM-with-D435i) and I am able to create 3D point clouds of the environment.
I am new in ROS and my goal is to bound a 3d box in a region of global pointcloud then transform the same box on RGB frames that are matched with that points(at the same coordinates) in the global point cloud.
now i have RGB, depth, and point cloud topic and tf but since i am new in this field i do not know how can i find RGB frames that are matched with each point in the global point cloud?
and how do the same operation from point cloud to RGB frames?
i would be grateful if someone can help me with that

Comment: @JWCS sorry for mentioning you here but i would be grateful if you could help me with this problem , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get 3D bounding box points.
- Transform them into camera's frame (z is depth).
- Generate your camera's calibration model (intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the camera, focal length etc.) -> Check [openCV model](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html), [Scaramuzza Model](https://sites.google.com/site/scarabotix/ocamcalib-toolbox) or another stereo camera calibration model
- Project 3D points to 2D pixels. (openCV has one `projectPoints()` function).

Comment: thank you for your answer, i just want to know is there any repository or script to do that?

Comment: why it is needed to do transformation before using projectPoints() ? as far as I know this function can directly project from the world coordinate to pixel coordinate...

Comment: @Hoseinshirali if the points are relative to the camera (camera is the origin) yup, no need to transform. But if both points and the camera is moving relative to another fix origin, first we need to find the points. (this functions assumes camera is in the origin 0,0,0).

Comment: another question, how can i transform these points into camera's frame ? is there any function to do that? thank you